# nginx 404 with server_name but okay with location path

Tags: nginx

I'm just learning nginx. I cannot understand why the server_name in the address bar of the browser results in a page not found (e.g. mydomain/app2.com, but the location of the directory is okay (e.g. mydomain/app2). I do understand that the server_name is not evaluated if the listen directive is conclusive.
I have a file [webroot]/app2/index.html that show a simple message.

Below is the edited portion of nginx.conf, generated with the command nginx -T.

```
    worker_processes        auto;
#worker_cpu_affinity    auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;

include conf.d/main.conf;

events {
    use             epoll;
    multi_accept    on;
    accept_mutex    off;
    worker_connections 1024;

    include conf.d/events.conf;
}

http {
    include         mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  off;
    #access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,facility=local7,tag=nginx_access,nohostname main;
    error_log   syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,facility=local7,tag=nginx_error,nohostname error;

    tcp_nopush  on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    sendfile        on;
    server_tokens   off;

    proxy_request_buffering     off;
    fastcgi_request_buffering   off;
    scgi_request_buffering      off;

    proxy_buffering     off;
    fastcgi_buffering   off;
    scgi_buffering      off;

    resolver_timeout              5s;
    client_header_timeout         10s;
    client_body_timeout           60s;
    send_timeout                  60s;
    keepalive_timeout             65s 20s;
    client_max_body_size          0;
    server_names_hash_max_size    8192;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    ssl_certificate           /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam               /usr/syno/etc/ssl/dh2048.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_session_tickets       off;
    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout       3600s;

    real_ip_header            X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive         on;
    set_real_ip_from          127.0.0.1;

    include     /var/tmp/nginx/trusted_proxy/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    server_tag     "nginx";

    gzip_disable    "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_vary       on;
    gzip_static     on;

    open_file_cache          max=1000 inactive=60s;
    open_file_cache_valid    3s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;

    upstream synoscgi {
        server unix:/run/synoscgi.sock;
    }

    index index.html index.htm index.php;


    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        gzip on;

        server_name _;

        location ~ ^/volume(?:X|USB|SATA|Gluster)?\d+/ {
            internal;

            root /;

            open_file_cache off;

            include app.d/x-accel.*.conf;
            include conf.d/x-accel.*.conf;
        }

        include app.d/www.*.conf;
        include app.d/alias.*.conf;
        include /usr/syno/share/nginx/conf.d/www.*.conf;
        include conf.d/www.*.conf;

        location = /webdefault/images/logo.jpg {
            alias /usr/syno/share/nginx/logo.jpg;
        }

        error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 @error_page;

        location @error_page {
            root /usr/syno/share/nginx;
            rewrite (.*) /error.html break;
            allow all;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
            root /var/lib/letsencrypt;
            default_type text/plain;
        }

        include app.d/.location.webstation.conf*;

        location / {
            rewrite ^ / redirect;
        }

        location ~ ^/$ {
            rewrite / http://$host:5000/ redirect;
        }
    }

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/app.d/dsm.DownloadStation.conf:
location ~ ^/volume(?:X|USB|SATA|Gluster)?\d+/ {
    internal;

    root /;

    open_file_cache off;

    include app.d/x-accel.*.conf;
    include conf.d/x-accel.*.conf;
}

location ~ ^/download/btsetting.cgi {
    rewrite /download/btsetting.cgi /webman/3rdparty/DownloadStation/dlm/btsetting.cgi break;
    include     scgi_params;
    scgi_pass   synoscgi;

}
location ~ ^/webman/modules/DownloadStation/dlm/(.*) {
    rewrite /webman/modules/DownloadStation/dlm/(.*) /webman/3rdparty/DownloadStation/dlm/$1 break;
    include     scgi_params;
    scgi_pass   synoscgi;

}


uninitialized_variable_warn    off;

if ($fqdn = false) {
    set $fqdn "";
}

scgi_param  HOST               $fqdn if_not_empty;

scgi_intercept_errors          on;


# configuration file /etc/nginx/app.d/.location.webstation.conf:
location ~ ^/~([^\/]*)/ {
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Redirect;
    proxy_read_timeout      3600s;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-By  $server_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-HTTPS         $https;
    proxy_set_header        X-Port          $server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-Port     $remote_port;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_intercept_errors  off;

    error_page 404 /_webstation_/404.html;
    return 404;

}

location ^~ /_webstation_/ {
    alias   /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/;
}

location ~ ^ {
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Redirect;
    proxy_read_timeout      3600s;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-By  $server_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-HTTPS         $https;
    proxy_set_header        X-Port          $server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-Port     $remote_port;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_intercept_errors  off;

    error_page 502 /_webstation_/$status.html;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/webstation_default.sock;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/app.d/server.webstation-vhost.conf:


server {

    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;

    listen      443 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name app3.com;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/lib/letsencrypt;
        default_type text/plain;
    }

    root    "/volume1/web/app3";
    index    index.html  index.htm  index.cgi  index.php  index.php5 ;
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 500 501 502 503 504 505 @error_page;

    location @error_page {
        root /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page;
        rewrite ^ /$status.html break;
    }

    location ^~ /_webstation_/ {
        alias    /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/;
    }

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/05d0bb2f-bd06-4069-ba12-eb4f67b58137/user.conf*;

}


server {

    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;

    listen      443 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name app2.com;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/lib/letsencrypt;
        default_type text/plain;
    }

    root    "/volume1/web/app2";
    index    index.html  index.htm  index.cgi  index.php  index.php5 ;
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 500 501 502 503 504 505 @error_page;

    location @error_page {
        root /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page;
        rewrite ^ /$status.html break;
    }

    location ^~ /_webstation_/ {
        alias    /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/;
    }

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/e0fd8b64-e801-426b-86b6-c0035b4ae9d7/user.conf*;

}



# configuration file /etc/nginx/app.d/server.webstation.conf:
server {
    listen  unix:/run/webstation_default.sock;
    root    /var/services/web;
    index   index.html index.php index.cgi;

    set_real_ip_from unix:;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

    fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
    fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
    fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
    fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME         $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI         $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param   HTTPS               $http_x_https if_not_empty;
    fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

    fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT         $http_x_real_port;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR         $http_x_forwarded_by;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT         $http_x_port;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME         $host;
    fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors            on;
    fastcgi_read_timeout                3600s;

    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 500 501 502 503 504 505 @error_page;

    location @error_page {
        root /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page;
        rewrite ^ /$status.html break;
    }

    location ^~ /_webstation_/ {
        alias   /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/;
    }
    location ~* \.(php[345]?|phtml)$ {

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-9f1e642a-0d20-4664-8934-c51d34f609de.sock;

    }
    location ~* \.cgi {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/fcgiwrap.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'I cannot understand why the server_name in the address bar of the browser results in a page not found (e.g. mydomain/app2.com, but the location of the directory is okay (e.g. mydomain/app2)' ? Are you browsing `mydomain/app2.com` and getting a 404 ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly what the questions says.When browsing to mydomain/app2.com I get an 404 error. When browsing to mydomain/app2 I get no error.

Comment: `mydomain/app2.com` is not a valid uri. Did you mean mydomain.com/app2 ?

Comment: Thanks. You have answered my question. I now understand the problem.